# google calendar api - events list in wrong order

Tags: google-calendar-api

sometimes the events list specifies a canceled event in a recurrence before the recurring event itself.
this doesnt make sense. its like creating a child before its parent...

please see the example list below (received from google api). the first event is the canceled event and only after is the recurrence it belongs to

````
[{
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3351534257460000\"",
    "id": "3cuva67b29fet1joar70n1vvf4_20230301T084500Z",
    "status": "cancelled",
    "recurringEventId": "3cuva67b29fet1joar70n1vvf4_R20230208T084500",
    "originalStartTime": {
      "dateTime": "2023-03-01T10:45:00+02:00",
      "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3351534257460000\"",
    "id": "3cuva67b29fet1joar70n1vvf4_R20230208T084500",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?private",
    "created": "2021-11-28T11:55:13.000Z",
    "updated": "2023-02-07T10:52:08.757Z",
    "summary": "private",
    "creator": {
      "email": "private@gmail.com"
    },
    "organizer": {
      "email": "private.calendar.google.com",
      "displayName": "private",
      "self": true
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2023-02-08T10:45:00+02:00",
      "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2023-02-08T11:35:00+02:00",
      "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem"
    },
    "recurrence": [
      "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY"
    ],
    "iCalUID": "private@google.com",
    "sequence": 1,

    "reminders": {
      "useDefault": false
    },
    "eventType": "default"
  }
]```
````

Comment: What's the API call that you made to get that result? And how was the parent event created? Strangely, even the parent event's ID looks like a child event because parent event IDs usually don't have timestamps.

Comment: @Daniel the api call was simply calendar.events.list
the parent was created in google calendar by a user who also uses our system. i dont know more than that. but this parent with id_timestamp structure is pretty common when a recurrence get split (not always though).

Comment: In my tests the child events showed up after the parents, but according to the [`events.list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) documentation the default order is "an unspecified, stable order". You could try to set `orderBy` to `startTime` or `updated` and see if the order changes. If you think this is a bug you can consider submitting it as feedback on Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906&pli=1)